# Quando devo usar ou não o new?

Tags: data, groovy

O que ocorre aqui? Por que se cria uma instancia de `Date` nesse exemplo:

```
String dataFormatada = new Date().format("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Já nesse exemplo não se usou o `new`:

```
def data = Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', '31/12/1980')
```

Quando devo usar ou não o new?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa usar o `new` sempre for instanciar uma classe, ou seja, criar uma nova instância de determinado objeto. Nesse caso, quando você cria uma nova instância de `Date` ela já vem com a data atual.

No exemplo

```
def data = Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', '31/12/1980')
```

Você não está criando uma nova instância de `Date` e é por isso que não precisas usar o `new`. O `parse` é um método estático, que retorna um objeto do tipo `Date`. Nesse caso, ele recebe uma `String` e o formato da mesma e devolve (retorna) o `Date` referente.

Answer (score 5):

@Aline, não se usa `new` em `def data = Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', '31/12/1980')`, pois `Date#parse(String, String)` é um método estático não um construtor, e, olhando a classe `Date`, esse método retorna uma instancia de `Date` retirada de um objeto `Calendar` pelo método `Calendar#getTime`.

Comment: Acho que se fizesse um merge dessa resposta com a do durtto ficaria bem completo :)

Comment: O jbueno já editou a dele :D

Answer (score 2):

> String dataFormatada = new Date().format("dd/MM/yyyy")

A String `dataFormatada` está recebendo a data de hoje no formato "dd/MM/yyyy";

> def data = Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', '31/12/1980')

`data` está recebendo o valor '31/12/1980'. Como já tem a data, não precisa do `new`.

`new Date()` vai retornar a data de hoje para você, e o format é para formatar do jeito que você quiser.

Comment: aH, é só por isso?

Comment: Sim. New Date vai retornar a data de hoje para você. e o format é para formatar do jeito que você quiser.

Comment: entendi. Obrigada!

Comment: por nada. é um  prazer ajudar.

Comment: okay. Valeu. Isso vale para outros exemplos também? Como setar um nome de uma pessoa etc?

Comment: tem outra forma para eu falar com vc? durtto

Comment: @AlineGonz http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha

Comment: Aline, aguarde um momento. Não escolha ainda. Talvez lhe passamos um  contexto errado.

Comment: Eu acho que ficou um pouco superficial, talvez se você aprofundasse um pouco mais seria melhor

Comment: o segundo não usa new pois é um método estático da classe(static). Foi uma resposta que obtive sobre
 def data = Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', '31/12/1980')
por isso que não foi utilizado o new. e aí?

Comment: Métodos estáticos podem ser acessados diretamente da classe, sem ser de um objeto, @Aline.

Comment: okay Gustavo, entendi.